# Have we found another earthlike planet?

Tags: colonization, planet, exoplanet

Space Colonization has become a popular trend in Sci-Fi movies. It would be a thrilling experience if we could travel from planet to planet.

Have we found another earth-like planet close enough for us to travel there for a Honeymoon and back to earth whenever we want?

Answer (score 1):

No and there will never be such a thing. Basic relativity theory predicts that any space ship traveling faster than the speed of light could also be used as a time machine, and of course with a time machine come many paradoxes. One of them is the [grandfather paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox), but the more your study the topic, the more paradoxes pop up. From my experience with physicists, the more they study relativity, the more certain they are that light speed cannot be broken. For an introduction I suggest you read "The Elegant Universe" by Brian Greene.

We are finding more and more promising candidates for possibly habitable worlds, however, even though we have only studied a [tiny portion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_%28spacecraft%29#Field_of_view) of the sky in detail. This may lead one to conclude that a habitable world is within a few light-years of the earth in some direction.

A word of caution, though: Until now, we have only detected earth-sized planets [indirectly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoplanet#Detection_methods), so for all we know, they might be tiny gas giants, or as uninhabitable as Venus. And to travel to even the nearest of them is [far beyond our current capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_travel#Challenges). Even if we allow for several lifetimes of travel.